# What is causing a one keypress delay?

Tags: javascript, html

When I type something it gets delayed by one keypress. for example if I type `h`, it would be blank, if i type `helloworld` it would be `helloworl`. If I have `sad` displayed, I would have to press backspace twice to get to `sa` instead of once. Why is there this delay? How do I fix it?

```html
<input type="text" id = "new"></input>
<p id = "result"></p>
<script src = "script.js" type = "module"></script>
```

```js
var search = document.getElementById("new");
var resultbox = document.getElementById("result");
search.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
  resultbox.innerHTML = search.value;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keydown` or `keypress` is execed before the new character is added to the value of the element.

you can use `input` or `keyup` event.

```js
search.addEventListener("input", function(){
  resultbox.innerHTML = search.value;
})
```

Comment: Be aware that in `keypress` you still can access the character being pressed via `e.key` or `e.keyCode`.